# Xcode 6: scroll view when the keyboard is shown scrolls higher than needed

Tags: keyboard, scrollview, xcode6

I have just installed Xcode 6.0.1. 
My application uses the following method to scroll the view up when the keyboard hides textboxes. It worked great with Xcode 5:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;

    // Depending on the orientation, the application chooses height or width of the keyboard to scroll
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
        frame.size.height -= kbSize.height;

    }else{
        frame.size.height -= kbSize.width;
    }

    CGPoint fOrigin = activeField.frame.origin;
    fOrigin.y -= self.scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    fOrigin.y += activeField.frame.size.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(frame, fOrigin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y + activeField.frame.size.height - frame.size.height);
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}
```

However in Xcode 6, the view scrolls much higher, going way beyond the view limits. It scrolls even when I select the textfields that are not hidden by the keyboard. Does anyone know what was changed in the new version that affects this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on solution of **Igor Tupitsyn**, I've wrote this code, that works in both *iOS7* and *iOS8*

I've tested it with success on

- **iPhone6 ( iOS 8.0.2 )**
- **iPhone5S ( iOS 8.0 )**
- **iPhone5 ( iOS 7.1.2 )**

---

```
//initialization in your init method

self.handledScrollView = <YOUR SCROLL VIEW>;
self.handledScrollviewOldContentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
self.handledScrollviewOldScrollIndicatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
self.isKeyboardShown = NO;


-(void) myKeyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note
{
    if (!self.handledScrollView)
        return;

    CGSize kbSize = [[note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);

    if (!self.isKeyboardShown){
        self.handledScrollviewOldContentInset = self.handledScrollView.contentInset;
        self.handledScrollviewOldScrollIndicatorInset =     self.handledScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets;
    }


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    NSValue* valAnimDuration = [note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval duration = 0;
    [valAnimDuration getValue:&duration];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];

    // save current inset state
    self.handledScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.handledScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // Scroll the table view to see the TextField just above the keyboard
    if (self.activeTextFieldInScrollView && !self.isKeyboardShown)
    {
        CGRect textFieldRect = [self.handledScrollView convertRect:((UIView*)self.activeTextFieldInScrollView).bounds fromView:self.activeTextFieldInScrollView];
        [self.handledScrollView scrollRectToVisible:textFieldRect animated:NO];
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    self.isKeyboardShown = YES;

}

-(void) myKeyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note
{
    if (!self.handledScrollView)
        return;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    NSValue* valAnimDuration = [note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval duration = 0;
    [valAnimDuration getValue:&duration];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];

    // restore insets and reset old state
    self.handledScrollView.contentInset = self.handledScrollviewOldContentInset;
    self.handledScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = self.handledScrollviewOldScrollIndicatorInset;

    self.handledScrollviewOldContentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.handledScrollviewOldScrollIndicatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    self.isKeyboardShown = NO;

}
```

this works properly also with different keyboard sizes (standard, emotion and any custom keyboard), and also when you show or hide with your finger the accessory view provided by the default iOS8 keyboard

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar problem - the textfield flies off the top of the screen when the Keyboard comes up!

Seems as though in iOS8.0 the keyboard dimensions are flip flopped when compared to iOS 7.0.3.  Here's some output from my iPad app which runs in landscape (only in landscape):

iOS 7.0.3:

```
 <0x7c4b4600 EditSignViewController.m:(1060)> the text fieldis <UITextField: 0x7b2dbd10; frame = (611 473; 90 30); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7b2dc850>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b2dbe50>>
 <0x83174f10 MasterSignFilterViewController.m:(461)> kbsize is {352, 1024}
 <0x83174f10 MasterSignFilterViewController.m:(462)> kbsize.height is: 1024.000000
 <0x83174f10 MasterSignFilterViewController.m:(463)> kbsize.width is: 352.000000
```

Here's the same output, but running iOS 8:

```
 <0x7d96d000 EditSignViewController.m:(1060)> the text fieldis <UITextField: 0x80af8c40; frame = (611 473; 90 30); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x851ab520>; layer = <CALayer: 0x80af8d80>>
 <0x7c570f20 MasterSignFilterViewController.m:(422)> kbsize is {1024, 352}
 <0x7c570f20 MasterSignFilterViewController.m:(423)> kbsize.height is: 352.000000
 <0x7c570f20 MasterSignFilterViewController.m:(424)> kbsize.width is: 1024.000000`
```

It appears to me that the keyboard dimensions coordinates are now rotating in iOS 8 when the device is rotated, whereas in iOS 7 it was static...

I made a quick test - MasterDetail iPad app, Scrollview with textfield,  registered for KB notifications and spit out some details when the KB comes onscreen.

Pertinent code:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"KB coming up!");
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    NSLog(@"kbsize is %@", NSStringFromCGSize(kbSize));
    NSLog(@"kbsize.height is: %f", kbSize.height);
    NSLog(@"kbsize.width is: %f", kbSize.width);
}
```

Looks like the iOS 8 KB is a bit taller (due to the predictive results being shown) and now rotates it's dimensions when the screen is in landscape:

8.0 Landscape

```
2014-09-25 11:32:45.511 BKTest[2788:223360] KB coming up!
2014-09-25 11:32:45.512 BKTest[2788:223360] kbsize is {1024, 391}
2014-09-25 11:32:45.512 BKTest[2788:223360] kbsize.height is: 391.000000
2014-09-25 11:32:45.512 BKTest[2788:223360] kbsize.width is: 1024.000000
```

7.0.3 Landscape

```
2014-09-25 11:34:43.677 BKTest[2891:70b] KB coming up!
2014-09-25 11:34:43.677 BKTest[2891:70b] kbsize is {352, 1024}
2014-09-25 11:34:43.677 BKTest[2891:70b] kbsize.height is: 1024.000000
2014-09-25 11:34:43.678 BKTest[2891:70b] kbsize.width is: 352.000000
```

iOS 8.0 Portrait

```
2014-09-25 11:29:43.235 BKTest[2741:220963] KB coming up!
2014-09-25 11:29:43.237 BKTest[2741:220963] kbsize is {768, 303}
2014-09-25 11:29:43.238 BKTest[2741:220963] kbsize.height is: 303.000000
2014-09-25 11:29:43.238 BKTest[2741:220963] kbsize.width is: 768.000000
```

7.0.3 Portrait

```
2014-09-25 11:34:19.796 BKTest[2891:70b] KB coming up!
2014-09-25 11:34:19.797 BKTest[2891:70b] kbsize is {768, 264}
2014-09-25 11:34:19.797 BKTest[2891:70b] kbsize.height is: 264.000000
2014-09-25 11:34:19.797 BKTest[2891:70b] kbsize.width is: 768.000000
```

Comment: meierjo, you are right. Below, I show how I solved in iOS8. Now it is not iOS7 compatible though.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is either compatible with iOS7 or iOS8. Does not work similarly well in both. Anyways, this solved it in iOS8;

In viewDidLoad

```
// Scroll view size
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1024, 768);
```

The keyboardWasShown method:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{

    info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    CGRect aRect = self.scrollView.frame;

    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    CGPoint origin = activeField.frame.origin;
    origin.y -= self.scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y + activeField.frame.size.height - aRect.size.height);
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }

}
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [KeyboardHandler](https://github.com/p581581/KeyboardHandler).

It helps me handle the keyboard properly with only 1 line of code!